# Daphne refuses to connect websocket requests

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-channels

I have a developed a complex Django server consisting of several applications, making use of channels in combination with the Daphne server an reverse proxy uplink from Nginx. This is the site configuration from /etc/nginx/sites-available:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name django.mydomain.eu;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name django.mydomain.eu;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/django.mydomain.eu/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/django.mydomain.eu/privkey.pem;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/django.mydomain.eu.access.log combined;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/django.mydomain.eu.error.log info;
  location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
  }
}
```

Both HTTP and Websocket requests are forwarded to Daphne on port 8000. HTTP works fine. Websocket works fine if coming from the Python client, the connections are made somewhat like this:

```
from websocket import WebSocket
while self.do_run:
  try:
    self.ws = WebSocket()
    self.ws.connect(self.dbline.wsserver+'ws/predictions/')
    break
  except (BrokenPipeError, 
        TimeoutError,
        WebSocketBadStatusException, 
        ConnectionRefusedError,
        WebSocketConnectionClosedException,
        WebSocketAddressException,
        OSError,
      ):
    self.logger.warning('BrokenPipe or Timeout while resetting '
      + 'prediction websocket server')
    sleep(djconf.getconfigfloat('long_brake', 1.0))
```

Websocket does not work when coming from the JavaScript section of a Django
template, where the connections are made like this:

```
function WSAsync(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result = {};
    result.tracker = 0;
    result.socket = new WebSocket(url);
    result.socket.onerror = ((event) => {
      console.error("WebSocket error:", url);
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Retry...");
        resolve(WSAsync(url));
      },10000);
    });
  });
};
```

This kind of Websocket connects to Daphne and is disconnected after maybe a second again, as you can see from this excerpt from the Django console log:

```
INFO WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/trigger/ [127.0.0.1:49410]
INFO WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/trigger/ [127.0.0.1:49410]
```

The relevant consumer is killed after a while:

```
WARNING Application instance <Task pending name='Task-21' coro=<ASGIStaticFilesHandler.__call__() 
running at /home/cam_ai/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles
/handlers.py:101> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at 
/home/cam_ai/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py:385, Task.task_wakeup()]>> for 
connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['127.0.0.1', 43264] path=b'/ws/c_view/'> took too long to 
shut down and was killed.
```

This is how I call the Django system:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload
```

The faulty behavior does not happen on my development system, only on the production system. these two PCs are very much identical in hardware. The development PC is sitting behind a router with DHCP in my office and the other is located in a server housing location with a defined single IP address. After one day I ran out of ideas how to debug further, what could be the reason for this strange effects?

I tried to fix by many variations of the Nginx-configurations, but the problem persisted. I was not able to find a way to get some more information from Daphne about the reason of connection refusal. I expected my clients from outside to connect also the Websocket links...

*** Edit ***
There is nothing wrong with the above setup. The error miraculously disappeared when I fixed a bad misconfiguration in another (not related) section of the server software...